# Make all the elemant zero except max n element in each row in numpy 2d-array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a 2D `numpy` array like:

```
[[1, 8, 3, 4, 5],
 [10,13,13,12,15]]
```

I want to convert all the elements to zero except the maximum or maximum 2 elements in each row. The output I'd like to get is:

```
[[0, 8, 0,0, 5],
 [0,13,13,0,15]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For solving this problem, we need to sort your data. If x is your numpy array data, at the first we sort it.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,8,3,4,5],[10,13,13,12,15]])
x.sort()
```

After sorting only two final elements of each rows show max values. So, we zero value is lied for another elements and we save `x` in `f`.

```
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    x[i][0:-2]=0
f = x
```

Then, `f` is:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  5,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 13, 15]])
```

Now we needinitial `x` and `f`:

```
x = np.array([[1,8,3,4,5],[10,13,13,12,15]])
```

`x` is:

```
array([[ 0,  8,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0, 13, 13,  0, 15]])
```

Finally, we compare `x` and `f` for reach to our goal:

```
for i in range(0,len(f)):
    for j in range(0,len(f[i])):
        if x[i][j] not in f[i]:
            x[i][j]=0
```

`RESULT` for `x` will be like this:

```
array([[ 0,  8,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0, 13, 13,  0, 15]])
```

Answer (score 5):

**with only one line of code and without loops**:

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 8, 3, 4, 5],
                [10,13,13,12,15]])
n_max = 2 # second max element

a * (a >= np.sort(a, axis=1)[:,[-n_max]]).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  8,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0, 13, 13,  0, 15]])
```

to do the same with columns...

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 8, 3, 4, 5],
                [10,13,13,12,15],
                [6, 9, 12,7, 7],
                [3, 8, 5 ,22, 2]])
n_max = 2 # second max element

a * (a >= np.sort(a, axis=0)[[-n_max],:]).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 13, 13, 12, 15],
       [ 6,  9, 12,  0,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 22,  0]])
```

Comment: @user2955839 correct and fastest solution as of 2020 here!

Comment: can you please also show how to get the max value of columns too? :)

Comment: @MH I did, it's the same logic

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(x):
    x[np.argwhere(x != x.max())] = 0
    return x

arr = np.array([[1, 8, 3, 4, 5],
               [10,13,13,12,15]])

new_arr = np.apply_along_axis(func,  1, arr)
```

You can modify the function "func" for largest 2 numbers. The above snippet replaces all the elements with 0 except the largest one in every row.

Update : For doing it with largest n elements you can use the following function in apply,

```
n = 2
def func(x):
    global n
    idx = (-x).argsort()[n:]
    x[idx] = 0
    return x

arr = np.array([[1, 8, 3, 4, 5],
               [10,13,13,12,15]])

new_arr = np.apply_along_axis(func,  1, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for only identifying max in row and and replacing all the other values as zero.
If you want to include top 2 highest value, I think you need to write for loop.

```
   import numpy as np
   import copy

   a = np.array([[1, 8, 3, 4, 5],
     [10,13,13,12,15]])

   b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

a == np.max(a) will raise an error in the future, so here's a tweaked version that will continue to broadcast correctly.

```
# get max by row and convert from (n, ) -> (n, 1) which will broadcast
row_maxes = a.max(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
```

if the update needs to be in place, you can do

```
a[:] = np.where(a == row_maxes, row_maxes, 0)

>> a
 array([[ 0,  8,  0,  0,  0],
           [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 15]])
```

---

You can identify max 2 from each row and apply for loop to get the desired result.

```
b = np.sort(b)
max_two = np.array(list(map(lambda row : row[-2:], b)))

for i, row in enumerate(a):
   for j, elm in enumerate(row):
      if elm not in max_two:
         a[i][j] = 0

>> a
array([[ 0,  8,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0,  13,  13,  0, 15]])
```